# Unused / Used Constants for Tests

Tags: java, syntax, compiler-warnings

I got a bunch of constants that I use for my tests.
They look like this  :

```
//Canada 
private final static String CA_QUEBEC = "CA/Québec/Québec";
private final static String CA_VANCOUVER = "CA/British Columbia/Vancouver";

//USA
private final static String US_LOS_ANGELES = "US/California/Los Angeles";
private final static String US_NEW_YORK = "US/District of Columbia/New York";

//FRANCE
private final static String FR_PARIS = "FR/Paris/Paris";
```

etc.
The goal of my test is to run my application quickly while using *one of these constants* : 
For instance :

```
    String cityPath = FR_PARIS;
```

Nevertheless, as I use only *one of them*, I must surround every constant with a suppress warning annotation (except the one I use, see below):

```
    //Canada 
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final static String CA_QUEBEC = "CA/Québec/Québec";
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final static String CA_VANCOUVER = "CA/British Columbia/Vancouver";
```

So that the compiler doesn't complain about those constants not beeing use although they are declared. Moreover, when I choose one of these constants, I then got another warning telling me that I used the suppresswarning annotation but my constant is actually beeing used.

If I want to get rid of all warnings, I should then spend my time putting and removing those annotations, and that's quite unconfortable to my mind.

So, how can I get a clean, warning free code in such a case. I am looking for a simple yet elegant solution (i.e. not introspection for instance).

Thanks to all, Stack Over Flow is really a cool place. :)

Stéphane

Comment: If the other constants never get used what are they for? Are you re-running your test by changing what `cityPath` points to and recompiling to test different scenarios?

Comment: "US/District of Columbia/New York" <- this should probably be "US/New York/New York City"? Not that it matters to the question ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make them `public` or `protected`, and your warnings will go away.

It also seems like a code smell that you are manually changing them to run tests. Wouldn't it make more sense to have separate tests for each constant? If there's a lot of common code, then you can have a base class to extend from.

Comment: Cool I didn't know about that. But so logical... :) Thx 5 mn and I accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution: Mark your constants as public.

Comment: Cool I didn't know about that. But so logical... :) Thx even if you answered one min after @Jeremy Heiler